# Can I do image compositions using TransLoadIt?

Tags: transloadit

We want to clip the image into a circle and stamp another image (a frame/shadow) on top of it.

Right now we're running imagemagick to do this on our own server, I'm wondering if I can offload that operation to TransloadIt somehow to be more scalable.  It looks like TransLoadIt is running ImageMagick itself to do operations but not all ImageMagick capabilities are available.

Is this something we could possibly do using TransLoadIt?

Comment: There is a guide about watermarking on the website https://transloadit.com/demos/image-resize/watermarking

Comment: @grovesNL Thanks, that's half the puzzle.  What about cutting out the circle though?

Comment: I'm thinking maybe I can do this with SVG, I'll have to experiment.

Comment: I think that could probably be done if you can use a solid color for the area outside the circle, with a transparent circle area. Then it just becomes another watermark.

Comment: Well, the outer area has to be transparent, not a solid color.  Seems like the SVG support is not good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it should be possible to first stamp a watermark on it that contains an opaque background with a transparent circle. Then in a second step, you could set the opaque color to be transparent.